# java xml dom parsing

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have this project I'm working on where I want to parse an xml file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<projectlist>
  <project>
    <name>SuperDuperApp</name>
    <type>batch</type>
    <prod>
      <server>testserver01</server>
    </prod>
    <qa>
      <server>testserver01</server>
    </qa>
    <dev>
      <server>testserver01</server>
    </dev>
  </project>
  <project>
    <name>Calculator</name>
    <type>deploy</type>
    <prod>
      <server>testserver02</server>
      <server>testserver03</server>
      <server>testserver04</server>
    </prod>
    <qa>
      <server>testserver05</server>
      <server>testserver06</server>
      <server>testserver07</server>
    </qa>
    <dev>
      <server>testserver12</server>
      <server>testserver13</server>
      <server>testserver14</server>
    </dev>
  </project>
</projectlist>
```

With this method parsing the file and trying to print out in the format:

```
name: SuperDuperApp
type: batch
server: testserver01

name: Calculator
type: deploy
environment: dev
server: testserver12
server: testserver13
server: testserver14

etc.
public void parseXML() {
     ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
     HashSet hs = new HashSet();
    try {
        InputStream file = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                "/net/swing/sandbox/util/config/projectlist.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println("Root element: " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("project");

        System.out.println("Information of all servers...");

        for (int i=0;i<nList.getLength();i++){
            Node fstNode = nList.item(i);

            if (fstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element fstElement = (Element) fstNode;

                NodeList nameElementList = fstElement.getElementsByTagName("name");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameElementList.item(0);
                NodeList name = nameElement.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("project name: " + ((Node) name.item(0)).getNodeValue());
                hs.add(((Node) name.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                NodeList typeElementList = fstElement.getElementsByTagName("type");
                Element typeElement = (Element) typeElementList.item(0);
                NodeList type = typeElement.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("Deploy type: " + ((Node) type.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                //print out server list can't do it for some reason         
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


     try {
     al.clear();
     al.addAll(hs);
     Collections.sort(al);
     for (int z = 0; z < al.size(); z++) {
     listModel.addElement(al.get(z));
     }
     } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
     lstProject.validate();

}
```

So I rewrote my method and now I'm just stuck <---newb

Comment: You see to have used the inner loop variable "j" inside the header for that loop - is that intended? Looks iffy to me

Comment: Why are you using DOM for this? It would be so much easier in XSLT or XQuery. Even if you are wedded to procedural languages, JDOM and XOM are far more usable than DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation for [Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html). Each node has a method [`getChildNodes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getChildNodes%28%29). Check that for the existence of children nodes and than iterate over them like you are doing.

Comment: I'll try that and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

If your xml was created using an xsd schema, you could instead use [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) to create classes for it, using the xjc tool. That should make your life a bit easier.

Comment: +1 - You could also use JAXB annotations to map existing classes to the XML structure, no XML schema required.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's appropriate to use XSLT transform in your case (much less boilerplate code) Look at [TransformerFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html) and java api for xml processing.

Comment: IMHO and experience, XSLT is never very user friendly or easy to use. Much prefer pure Java myself.

Comment: IMHO and experience, developers get about as much out of XSLT as they put into it, which usually isn't very much.

Answer (score 0):

As a q&d solution you could apply the same strategy as for getting "project" node:

```
...
System.out.println("servers:");

NodeList sList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("server");
for (int i = 0; i < sList.getLength(); i++) {
    String stuff = sList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
    System.out.println(stuff);
}
```